# Firefox align-items combined with rotate()

Tags: css, firefox, flexbox, cross-browser

I'm trying to create a rotated header for a compact table, and it works fine in Chrome but not Firefox.

Code:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

span {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  transform: rotate(200deg);
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 35px !important;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span><b>Hello</b> world</span>
  <span><b>Foo</b> bar</span>
</div>
```

In Chrome (and Edge) I get:

[image]

In Firefox I get:

[image]

If I take the `align-items: center` out I get the same behaviour in all browsers, but I obviously lose my alignment:

[image]

I guess I can hack this with padding, but I'd rather know what it's doing for future reference.

Comment: which version of firefox? I'm getting same in both

Comment: @kukkuz is right on 66.02 looks well

Comment: Ah! You're right, I was on 57 still, thought I'd updated it but I hadn't. Still getting a different weird issue on 66.0.3 for the Mac, but that is irrelevant for this project. @kukkuz - if you add "Upgrade Firefox" as an answer I'll mark it as correct

Comment: np, its trivial right :)